# How does Java parse empty statements?

Tags: java, parsing, compiler-errors

```
if( 3 % 3 == 0){
    return 3;;
}
```

Java says `unreachable statement`.

I understand that `java` parses `return 3;;` as

```
return 3;  
        ;
```

So It says unreachable statement. But it is empty statement. Why does java care about it?

Comment: Why would they bother special-casing empty statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: the Java compiler treats an empty statement as just a statement. As [this section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5) from the Java language specification indicates:

```
Statement:

   StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement
   LabeledStatement
   IfThenStatement
   IfThenElseStatement
   WhileStatement
   ForStatement

StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement:
   Block
   EmptyStatement
   ExpressionStatement
   AssertStatement
   SwitchStatement
   ...
```

And [the definition of unreachable statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21) applies to all types of statements. Note specifically the following:

> An empty statement can complete normally iff it is reachable.